# Google Compute Engine - Error on deployment

Tags: cloud, google

I think I might be missing something, but it won’t let me deploy with an SSD above 500gb

{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"QUOTA_EXCEEDED","ResourceErrorMessage":"Quota 'SSD_TOTAL_GB' exceeded. Limit: 500.0 in region us-west2."}

Am I doing something wrong, or should my boot disk not be that large and instead add extra drives after?

Answer (score 0):

To check if your exceeding your generals quotas you can go to the IAM and Admin page and select quota.

In your case, you are most likely exceeding the quota you have in that specific region to check that run the command below:

gcloud compute regions describe us-west2

If you are exceeding your quota, for details on what to do next I suggest you look at the following documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas)